# variables in variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the script tag, to retreive variable value inside a varible, i have used the following code but it does not return any value.

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {
       var data = {
        GetAnimals: function()
        {
        return 'tiger';         assign value to GetAnimals variable
        },
        GetBirds:function()
        {
        return 'pegion';       assign value to GetBirds variable
        }
        }
      });

      document.write(data.GetAnimals);//should print tiger
      document.write(data.GetAnimals);//should print pegion

      </script>
```

but,I could not print the desired result.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess `data` has local scope ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not calling the functions as functions:

```
document.write(data.GetAnimals());//should print tiger
document.write(data.GetBirds());//should print pegion
```

On top of that, you're trying to access `data` from *outside* `$(function() { ... });`, which by that time doesn't exist anymore.

```
$(function () {
    var data = {
      GetAnimals: function() {
        return 'tiger'; //        assign value to GetAnimals variable
      },
      GetBirds:function() {
        return 'pegion'; //      assign value to GetBirds variable
      }
    }

    document.write(data.GetAnimals());//should print tiger
    document.write(data.GetBirds());//should print pegion
  });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/afikem/1/)

Comment: @sachin Thanks, you are correct but when the code is included within jquey it is not working.I want to use it included in jquery for my context.

Comment: @BharathKumar I've updated the answer; you had another issue with scope.

Answer (score 1):

Never heard about "self invoked functions"?

```
var data = {
    GetAnimals: (function () {
            return 'tiger';
            // assign value to GetAnimals variable
        })(),
    GetBirds: (function () {
            return 'pegion';
            // assign value to GetBirds variable
        })()
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
   var data = {
        getAnimals: function() {
            return 'tiger';
        },

        getBirds: function() {
            return 'pigeon';  // I guess you meant pigeon
        }
    }
  });

  document.write(data.getAnimals()); // *call* the method
  document.write(data.getBirds()); // call the correct method
```

and please, use proper capitalization and indentation.